# Javascript functions keep looping exponentially...Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script in javascript/jquery that seeks to mimic a Wisconsin card sorting task (guess the matching-card rule), but that keeps looking exponentially starting from trial 3. See results of console logs, line 21 of the fiddle. What's wrong?

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vebsa4Lg/

```
var posfeed = "Right!";
var negfeed = "Wrong!";

var trials = ['GreenTriangle1','GreenTriangle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'RedCross4*GreenStar2*RedTriangle1*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'BlueTriangle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'RedCircle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'GreenStar4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'YellowCross1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'BlueTriangle4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'RedCircle3*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'GreenCross4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'YellowCircle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'GreenTriangle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCross4*GreenStar2*RedTriangle1*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'BlueTriangle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCircle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'GreenStar4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'YellowCross1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'BlueTriangle4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCircle3*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'GreenCross4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'YellowCircle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'GreenTriangle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCross4*GreenStar2*RedTriangle1*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'BlueTriangle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'RedCircle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'GreenStar4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'YellowCross1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'BlueTriangle4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'RedCircle3*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'GreenCross4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'YellowCircle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2','GreenTriangle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'RedCross4*GreenStar2*RedTriangle1*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'BlueTriangle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'RedCircle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'GreenStar4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'YellowCross1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'BlueTriangle4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'RedCircle3*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'GreenCross4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'YellowCircle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'GreenTriangle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCross4*GreenStar2*RedTriangle1*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'BlueTriangle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCircle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'GreenStar4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'YellowCross1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'BlueTriangle4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCircle3*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'GreenCross4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'YellowCircle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'GreenTriangle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'RedCross4*GreenStar2*RedTriangle1*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'BlueTriangle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2', 'RedCircle1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'GreenStar4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'YellowCross1*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*1', 'BlueTriangle4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'RedCircle3*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*3', 'GreenCross4*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*4', 'YellowCircle2*RedTriangle1*GreenStar2*YellowCross3*BlueCircle4*2'];

var resp;
var choice;
var fol = 0;
var i = 1;

$(function() {
        $("#feed").bind("click tap", function () {
            $("#feed").unbind("click");
            $("#feed").html("One moment...");
            Distribute(i, fol);
        });
    }); 

function Distribute(i, fol) {

    console.log('fol is ' + fol + ' and i is ' + i);

    if (fol >=4 && i<=10) {i=11;}
    if (fol >=4 && i<=20 && i>11) {i=21;}
    if (fol >=4 && i<=30 && i>21) {i=31;}
    if (fol >=4 && i<=40 && i>31) {i=41;}
    if (fol >=4 && i<=50 && i>41) {i=51;}
            if (fol >=4 && i > 50 && i<=60) {$("#feed").html("Task is over!");}
        if (fol < 4 && i==10) {i=1;}
        if (fol < 4 && i==20) {i=11;}
        if (fol < 4 && i==30) {i=21;}
        if (fol < 4 && i==40) {i=31;}
        if (fol < 4 && i==50) {i=41;}
        if (fol < 4 && i==60) {i=51;}
    setTimeout(function() {
            $('#feed').html('');
    var cur_trial = trials[i];
    var symb = cur_trial.split("*");

    $('#img1').html('<img src="CardSortTest/' + symb[1] + '.jpg" />');
    $('#img2').html('<img src="CardSortTest/' + symb[2] + '.jpg" />');
    $('#img3').html('<img src="CardSortTest/' + symb[3] + '.jpg" />');
    $('#img4').html('<img src="CardSortTest/' + symb[4] + '.jpg" />');
    $('#target').html('<img src="CardSortTest/' + symb[0] + '.jpg" />');
    resp=symb[5];
    Display(i, fol);
        },1500);
}

function Display(i, fol) {
                $("#img1").bind("click tap", function () {
                   choice = 1;
                    CheckResp(choice, i, fol);
                  // $("#img1").unbind("click");
            });
            $("#img2").bind("click tap", function () {
                   choice = 2;
                    CheckResp(choice, i, fol);
                   //$("#img2").unbind("click");
            });
            $("#img3").bind("click tap", function () {
                   choice = 3;
                    CheckResp(choice, i, fol);
                 // $("#img3").unbind("click");
            });
            $("#img4").bind("click tap", function () {
                   choice = 4;
                    CheckResp(choice, i, fol);
                 // $("#img4").unbind("click");
            });
        }


function CheckResp(gresp, i, fol) {
    $("#target").html('');
        i++;
    if (gresp == resp) {
    fol++;
            $("#feed").html(posfeed).promise().done(function(){ Distribute(i, fol); });
        }
    else { 
            $("#feed").html(negfeed).promise().done(function(){ Distribute(i, 0); });
        }

}
```

Comment: Love down voters who do not care to explain. Very useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rebinding the click handlers on the images in each call to `Display` - basically adding a new click handler each time. Each one of these is being invoked on each subsequent click.  That is, clicking on a card, adds a click handler to each card...for each click handler the card has.  You should only call `Display` once, not each time you distribute new cards. Since the handler is on the containing element, it will still fire despite changing the image inside it.

I've taken the liberty of updating your code to not use global variables and set the handlers up just once. It uses data values to hold the current values rather than global data.

See at http://jsfiddle.net/yk6s54x3/1/

Comment: Wow, thanks for finding out my stupid mistake. Your response really nails it. I really like the idea of adding data to `img` and using it back in a function with find. Didn't think of that, very clever.